# Bevelling Issue with Subdivision Surfaces

Tags: subdivision-surface, bevel

I have a modeling issue, could help me to solve this problem?

I want the marked edges to be bevelled (sharp) so that they keep
their form and get not distorted by the subdivision surface.

It's almost perfect, except the weird artifacts. i already tried to use
weighted normals which helps a bit but do not save the day.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You have to bevel the inner edge that goes from the corner as well, or use at least Edge Crease but its not as good as when you add suporting edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to illustrate Fowl's point.

You also need to bevel adjacent edges.
That way the bevel has enough geometry to work with.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, will try it out tmr!